# Impossible Task On Sql Calculation Where Date Is Equal

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

**

### LOOK AT MY ANSWER WHICH IS REFERE AS NEW QUESTION ON SAME PROBLEM.

**

I have Confusion against utilize **If,Else** Statement against calculation of stock By date. And sort the same by date.

**There is real challenge to calculate running total between equal date:**

1. If date is equal
2. If date is greater than
3. If date is less than

**My Table Schema Is:**

```
TransID     int,        Auto Increment

Date       datetime,
Inwards decimal(12,2)
Outward decimal(12,2)
```

**Suppose If I have Records as Below:**

```
TransID Date(DD/MM/YYYY)  Inward        Outward     

1       03/02/2011                        100                                       
2       12/04/2010                        200               
3       03/02/2011          400
```

**Than Result Should be:**

```
    TransID Date(DD/MM/YYYY)    Inward  Outward        Balance

    2         12/04/2010                      200         -200          
    1         03/02/2011                      100         -300                                  
    3         03/02/2011            400                    100
```

I wants to calculate **Inward - outwards = Balance** and Balance count as **running total** as above. but the condition that it should be as per **date order by Ascending**

How to sort and calculate it by date and transID?

What is transact SQL **IN SQL_SERVER-2000****?.

Comment: If you mouse over the "tsql" tag, you'll get a DHTML popup with a short summary of TSQL.  Is this for SQL Server, or Sybase?  Pls include version too.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by `How to sort and calculate it by date and transID?`.  As a result, show a sample result set (what you want) based on the given rows.  It would also be good if you add more rows to the given data.

Comment: @KM, How, Can You provide some example?.

Comment: @mahesh, you show 3 sample rows `Suppose If I have Records as Below:` show more like 10.  then show the result set that you need, based on the sample rows.  Using the actual values in your sample data, type in the results you need to get (show the column heading and all rows you need).  from looking at what data rows you have and what result you need, some one here will be able to write a query for you.  until then I have no idea what you need.  I can see your table schema and 3 sample rows, but have no idea what you what to do with that data.

Comment: @mahesh what do you mean by "If date is equal"? Equal to what? A parameter input? The current date? Perhaps it would help if you gave what the output should look like. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4887309/119477)

Comment: @KM, See my Edit I wants to return result on Balance Columns which is not in my table schema but it would be specify by query

Comment: @Conrad Frix, I edited my question, but the link you have provided is not match with my above question.

Comment: @mahesh - run the code I gave you. On the fourth line, change `from trans` to `from yourtablename`. The result is `-200, -300, 100`, in that order. Your listed result is incorrect because ID2 comes before ID1 in `date order`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a brute O(n<sup>2</sup>) approach of self-joining the table to itself, or if the table is large, it is better to iteratively calculate the balance.  The choices for SQL Server 2000 are limited, but the approach I will show uses a loop that traverses the table in `date, transid` order rather than using cursors.

Here is a sample table for discussion

```
create table trans (transid int identity, date datetime, inwards decimal(12,2), outward decimal(12,2))
insert trans select '20110203', null, 100
insert trans select '20100412', null, 200
insert trans select '20110203', 400, null  -- !same date as first
```

This is the T-SQL batch that will give you the output you require. If you merely wanted to update a balance column in the table (if it had such an extra column), change all references to #trans to the table itself.

```
-- fill a temp table with the new column required
select *, cast(null as decimal(12,2)) as balance
into #trans
from trans

-- create an index to aid performance
create clustered index #cix_trans on #trans(date, transid)

-- set up a loop to go through all record in the temp table
--   in preference to using CURSORs
declare @date datetime, @id int, @balance decimal(12,2)

select top 1 @date = date, @id = transid, @balance = 0
from #trans
order by date, transid

while @@ROWCOUNT > 0 begin
    update #trans set @balance = balance = @balance + coalesce(inwards, -outward)
    where transid = @id

    -- next record
    select top 1 @date = date, @id = transid
    from #trans
    where (date = @date and transid > @id)
       or (date > @date)
    order by date, transid
end

-- show the output
select *
from #trans
order by date, transid
;

-- clean  up
drop table #trans;
```

Output

```
2   2010-04-12 00:00:00.000 NULL    200.00  -200.00
1   2011-02-03 00:00:00.000 NULL    100.00  -300.00
3   2011-02-03 00:00:00.000 400.00  NULL    100.00
```

**EDIT**

If you need to show the final output using the date formatted to dd/mm/yyyy, use this

```
-- show the output
select transid, convert(char(10), date, 103) date, inwards, outward, balance
from #trans
order by #trans.date, transid
;
```

Comment: @cyberkiwi, your idea is good but result is not shown as aspect So first check the result of balance column and modify it for the same.

Comment: @cyberkiwi, Forget about my transaction, I have checked it as per your transaction which are created and inserted by you table trans and your result is -200,NULL,NULL. Check it.

Comment: @mahesh - you are right. I have now checked it and the results are as posted.

Comment: @cyberkiwi, See my answer post which is refer as question here, there is problem which is wrote in.

Comment: @cyberkiwi, your solution is works fine on datetime Date Field but Not in Varchar Date Field. What is the solution you have for the same?

Comment: @mahesh - start with a datetime field, but display end result in dd/mm/yyyy? - see edited end of answer

Comment: @cyberkiwi, yes the above is solved and you can find other way in my answer, but my first preference is your answer. I hereby accept your answer.

Comment: @cyberkiwi, I think Jeff answer is very easy way but there is little mistake is that balance counting not well. I think we can improve it by extra efforts what you say?.

Answer (score 2):

Is Balance (Inward-Outward) ?

```
select TransID,
   Date,
  Inward,
  Outward, 
  (select sum(Inward - Outward) 
        from tbl_name b1 
        where b1.TransID <= b.TransID) as RunB 
 from   tbl_name b 
 order by Date desc,TransID desc
```

This would order by Date in descending order - if the dates are same they are ordered by TransID

**Edit:**

Assume a Transaction table as this

```
select * from Transactions

1   NULL    100.00  2010-01-01 00:00:00.000
2   NULL    200.00  2010-01-02 00:00:00.000
3   400.00  NULL    2010-01-03 00:00:00.000
4   50.00   NULL    2010-01-03 00:00:00.000
5   NULL    100.00  2010-01-04 00:00:00.000
```

If you do this query ie, sort by TransactionIDs you would get this!

```
select TransID,
   Date,
  isNull(Inward,0.0),
  isNull(Outward,0.0), 
  (select sum(isNull(Inward,0.0) - isNull(Outward,0.0)) 
        from Transactions b1 
        where b1.TransID <= b.TransID) as RunB 
 from  Transactions b 
 order by Date asc,TransID asc

1   2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 0.00    100.00  -100.00
2   2010-01-02 00:00:00.000 0.00    200.00  -300.00
3   2010-01-03 00:00:00.000 400.00  0.00    100.00
4   2010-01-03 00:00:00.000 50.00   0.00    150.00
5   2010-01-04 00:00:00.000 0.00    100.00  50.00
```

Instead if you use this query - sort by date you would get this? Is this what you meant Mahesh?

```
select TransID,
   Date,
  isNull(Inward,0.0),
  isNull(Outward,0.0), 
  (select sum(isNull(Inward,0.0) - isNull(Outward,0.0)) 
        from Transactions b1 
        where b1.Date <= b.Date) as RunB 
 from  Transactions b 
 order by Date asc,TransID asc

1   2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 0.00    100.00  -100.00
2   2010-01-02 00:00:00.000 0.00    200.00  -300.00
3   2010-01-03 00:00:00.000 400.00  0.00    150.00
4   2010-01-03 00:00:00.000 50.00   0.00    150.00
5   2010-01-04 00:00:00.000 0.00    100.00  50.00
```

The difference in queries being -> (b1.**Date** <= b.Date) and (b1.**TransID** <= b.TransID)

Comment: @Jeff First of Thing is that you have not mention table name and other thing is that you have not count Balance as running total which is most important.

Comment: @mahesh - See the edited code; I used TransID to order them. The better way is to use Date column

Comment: @Jeff, yes you are right i wants to use this formula for date order and your transact sql is not shown result as aspect so try to use my above transaction and check your code.

Comment: @Jeff, I have already tried it before but fail to put result by date order, because there may equal,greater,less condition for date and we have to oder it by date from beginning to end.

Comment: @Jeff, There is real challenge to count running total between equal date.

Comment: @Jeff - as you are reordering the main data by Date, you should change your subquery to be b1.Date < b.Date

Comment: @ck, There is also have to use COALESCE Function to Nullable column calculaton. and I wants Order By date, transID is for supporting of date column.

Comment: @ck, Your suggestion not fulfill my requirement.

Comment: @mahesh - Let me try on my machine with equal date rows

Comment: @ck (b1.Date <= b.Date) or (b1.TransID <= b.TransID) possibly could result in diff results

Comment: @Jeff, Your solution is working but there is running total not work if date is equal for example  look at my Answer which is Refer as question.

Answer (score 0):

Now this is Solution with date in format **dd/MM/yyyy** of above question.

```
select *, cast(null as decimal(12,2)) as balance
into #trans
from stock

-- create an index to aid performance
create clustered index #cix_trans on #trans(date, transid)

--set up a loop to go through all record in the temp table
--   in preference to using CURSORs
declare @date datetime, @id int, @balance decimal(12,2)

select top 1 @date = date, @id = transid, @balance = 0
from #trans
order by date, transid

while @@ROWCOUNT > 0 begin
  update #trans set @balance = balance = @balance + coalesce(input, -output)
  where transid = @id

-- next record
select top 1 @date = date, @id = transid
from #trans
where (date = @date and transid > @id)
or (date > @date)
order by date, transid
end

-- show the output
select 
transID,
date= convert(varchar,convert(datetime,date,103),103), 
input, 
output, 
balance
from #trans
order by convert(datetime,date,103), transID

-- clean  up
drop table #trans;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take this first bit of cyberkiwi's solution:

```
select *, cast(null as decimal(12,2)) as balance
into #trans
from stock
```

and change it so the `nvarchar` dates from your table are converted to `datetime` values. That is, expand the `*` into the actual set of columns, replacing the date column with the converting expression.

Given the structure you've shown in your original question, it may look like this:

```
select
  TransID,
  convert(datetime, substring(Date,7,4) + substring(Date,4,2) + substring(Date,1,2)) as Date,
  Inward,
  Outward,
  cast(null as decimal(12,2)) as balance
into #trans
from stock
```

Leave the rest of the script untouched.

Comment: @Andriy M, it's throw Error Like: "Server: Msg 256, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The data type datetime is invalid for the substring function. Allowed types are: char/varchar, nchar/nvarchar, and binary/varbinary.
Server: Msg 256, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The data type datetime is invalid for the substring function. Allowed types are: char/varchar, nchar/nvarchar, and binary/varbinary.
Server: Msg 256, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The data type datetime is invalid for the substring function. Allowed types are: char/varchar, nchar/nvarchar, and binary/varbinary."

Comment: @mahesh: I think that means the `Date` column in your `stock` table is `datetime`. I thought it was `varchar`, because you said: `I wants to read date as dd/MM/yyyy hence I have alter the same as above but cyberkiwi's solution is works on date datatype datetime not to date datatype varchar`. I understand my modification is not needed then, and cyberkiwi's solution should work for you without any changes.

Comment: @Andriy M, You are right that I am having date field is datatype datetime but i wants to display it in dd/MM/yyyy Order. No doubt that cyberkiwi's solution working on datetime field but it won't on casting varchar date field.

Comment: @mahesh: Sorry, I'm confused now. So, all you need is to display the dates in the final result as `dd/MM/yyyy`? I didn't address that bit because I already saw that solved in your last script. Here's the line that converts `Date`: `date=convert(varchar,date,103),`. It's in your script already (the one you based on cyberkiwi's solution), what is wrong with that?

Comment: @Andriy M, yes but it would make wrong counting of balance column as because cyberkiwi's solution is on date(datetime) and if i cast it to varchar than it would ultimately affect the calculation.

Comment: @mahesh: No, you don't need to worry about that. Just look at your script again, the conversion happens *after* all calculations.